# Excel VBA: For Each loop set up

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

Edit: Added sample of raw data below

I run a claim report every month and copy the data into a tab. All of the data is organized into columns and I've been using a spreadsheet full of `SumProduct`'s and `CountIf`'s to count and organize the data based on different sets of criteria but it just takes too long to process so I'm trying to write a VBA sub to accomplish this more efficiently. One of the columns of data is "Adjuster Home Office". This column is basically a list of offices where each claim originated from. I used `AdvancedFilter` to extract all of the unique values in this column and copy them to a separate tab in column A. Then, in column C, below each location, I have a list of the claim types or "line items" handled at each office. I have no problem getting this part set up. In column D, I need to be able to display the count of each line item at that designated location. This is where all the `Countif`'s and `SumProduct`'s came into play in my old template I had been using. This is where I hit a snag. I'm trying to use For Each loops to count each line item in column B below the first location, then move to the next location in column A and repeat. Below is the code I've tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

Dim linerngs As Range
Dim lineitem As Range
Dim lastlinerow As Long
Dim wsf
Dim TabLastRow
Dim claimstab As String
Dim officesrange As Range
Dim office As Range

claimstab = Sheet2.Range("F2") & " Claims"

TabLastRow = Sheets(claimstab).Cells(Sheets(claimstab).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

officeslastrow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastlinerow = Sheet2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set officerng = Range("A6:A" & officeslastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
Set linerngs = Range("C7:C" & lastlinerow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

For Each office In officerng
    For Each lineitem In linerngs
        If InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "IN") > 0 And InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "AOS") = 0 Then
            lineitem.Offset(0, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheets(claimstab).Range("B2:B" & TabLastRow), office))
        End If
    Next lineitem
Next office


End Sub
```

I know this is incorrect because these loops are going to loop through everything in column B rather than just the line items below each location. So what I end up with is the count of the last location displayed for every line item in the entire column. below is an example of what I need it to look like. Right now, all im concerned with is setting up the loop to run correctly.

example of what I currently get
[[image: example of what I currently get]

example of what I'm trying to get
[[image: example of what I'm trying to get]

You can see from the first example that I'm getting the value "3" for everything.  I included a pivot of the locations and their values.  you can see that the last location in the pivot, South Portland, has a count of 3.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

example of raw data
[[image: example of raw data]

Objective
[[image: objective]

[[image: Line Items Source]
the list of line items is completed created by a userform asking for user imputs

Comment: Quick note when using multiple sheets, *always* explicitly state which sheet you're using, when using `Cells()`, `Range()`, `Rows.Count`, etc. For example, change your lines to `officeslastrow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (and same for other variable).

Comment: Atlanta, GA should be 7?

Comment: yes @findwindow , I made a mistake there.  Atlanta, GA should be 7

Comment: This _definitely_ won't be faster than formulas using VBA that loops over ranges.  It probably won't be faster using optimised VBA (eg loop over variant arrays).  It would be better to ask for help to optimise your formulas, initially anyway.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks i'll keep that in mind

Comment: @chrisneilsen so far, this is lightning fast compared to the formula template I've been using.

Comment: My point is that if your formulas are so slow, you are probably doing them wrong.  They should be fast too.  And if you persist with VBA, please look into variant arrays, they are orders of magnitude faster than looping ranges

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm also trying to safe guard this against user errors.  my co workers are novice level excel users at best.

Comment: any help on this would be awesome.  if I can get this figured out, I can basically finish the entire project

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but I think this is how I would approach your project. It would be helpful to see the raw data that you get in your report and paste into a spreadsheet.

First two assumptions (and you know what they say about assumptions)

1. The data is being pulled from a database and is returned as rows which may not be in order. For example:

```
 ATLANTA, GA     IN-AK, HI  3  IN-CA  2  ...  IncidentOnly  4
 BOCA RATON, FL  IN-AK, HI  3  IN-CA  6  ...  IncidentOnly  5 
 ATLANTA, GA     IN-AK, HI  1  IN-CA  0  ...  IncidentOnly  2 
 ...
 AURORA, IL      IN-AK, HI  7  IN-CA  3  ...  IncidentOnly  4
```

2. You want all of the insurance products summed for each office and then displayed in a prettier report format.

If these assumptions are true (or close to true), you could create a HomeOffice class that had a property for each type of insurance, then simply loop through the rows of data in the raw report and add each HomeOffice object to a collection so you get a unique list of offices.

An example from a similar sounding project I did:

```
Raw Data:
Mary    2   6
Sally   4   9
Mary    4   1
Sally   3   8
Joe     1   4
Bob     3   7
Mary    6   9
Sally   8   4
Bob     4   8
Joe     2   6
Joe     4   5

Formatted Data:
Mary       12      16
Sally      15      21
Bob         7      15
Joe         7      15
```

To do this, add a Class module (Insert -> Class Module) and change its name to HomeOffice. Insert this code into the class (some bits skipped so its not so long. Fill in where needed adding a property for each insurance product.)

```
Option Explicit

Private pOffice As String
Private pINAKI As Double
Private pINCA As Double
'... class properties left out for brevity
Private pIncidentOnly As Double


''''''''''''''''''''''
' Office property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Office() As String
    Office = pOffice
End Property
Public Property Let Office(Value As String)
    pOffice = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' INAKI property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get INAKI() As Double
    INAKI = pINAKI
End Property
Public Property Let INAKI(Value As Double)
    pINAKI = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' INCA property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get INCA() As Double
    INCA = pINCA
End Property
Public Property Let INCA(Value As Double)
    pINCA = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Add other propertied for the different product types
''''''''''''''''''''''
' Follow the same format as the other properties

''''''''''''''''''''''
' IncidentOnly property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get IncidentOnly() As Double
    IncidentOnly = pIncidentOnly
End Property
Public Property Let IncidentOnly(Value As Double)
    pIncidentOnly = Value
End Property
```

Now in your CommandButton23_Click sub add this code (again shortened for brevity, but hopefully you get the picture.):

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim HO As New HomeOffice

    'Collections can only have one Item, Key pair. 
    'We'll use the office location as the key to get a 
    'unique list of offices
    Set col = New Collection

    'Read in the raw data
    With Sheet1
        For r = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            'Check if the location has an existing HomeOffice object 
            If InCol(col, .Cells(r, 1)) Then
                'It does so get the existing object and total the values
                Set HO = col.Item(.Cells(r, 1))
                HO.Office = .Cells(r, 1)
                HO.INAKI = HO.INAKI + .Cells(r, 2)
                HO.INCA = HO.INCA + .Cells(r, 3)
                ' more properties
                HO.IncidentOnly = HO.IncidentOnly + .Cells(r, 10)
                'We have to remove the existing object and add it again
                'to reflect the updated totals
                col.Remove (.Cells(r, 1))
            Else
                'The location hasn't been added yet so create and add it
                HO.Office = .Cells(r, 1)
                HO.INAKI = .Cells(r, 2)
                HO.INCA = .Cells(r, 3)
                ' More properties
                HO.IncidentOnly = .Cells(r, 10)
            End If
            col.Add HO, .Cells(r, 1)
            'Important to clear our object or our totals are wrong! :)
            Set HO = Nothing
        Next r
    End With

    'Now we simply loop through our collection of offices and
    'print out the totals.
    r = 6 'The first office starts on row 6 in your picture
    With Sheet2
        For Each HO In col
            .Cells(r, "A").Value = HO.Office
            .Cells(r + 1, "C").Value = "IN - AK, HI"
            .Cells(r + 1, "F").Value = HO.INAKI
            .Cells(r + 2, "C").Value = "IN - CA"
            .Cells(r + 2, "F").Value = HO.INCA
            'Continuing on for all 10 types
            .Cells(r + 10, "C").Value = "Incident Only"
            .Cells(r + 10, "F").Value = HO.IncidentOnly
            Set HO = Nothing
            r = r + 13 'So the next office starts 13 rows later...Row 19 in your pic
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function InCol(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    'Returns TRUE if the object is in the collection or FALSE if it is not
    Dim obj As New HomeOffice

    On Error GoTo err
    InCol = True
    'If the key doesn't exist, it throws an error and set the function to false
    Set obj = col(key)
    Set obj = Nothing
    Exit Function

err:
        InCol = False
End Function
```

This is a drastically different approach, and involves some tougher concepts. Like I said, it may not work depending on how the raw data is formatted, but maybe it can give you a different way to approach your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate the response.  I'll try adapting these functions to my project.  The only problem I can see with it up front is that not every client gets charged the same rates, for the same states.  example: while one client may get charged the same rate for claims occurring in both TX & CA, another client may get charged separate rates for TX & CA.  this process involves a ton of dynamic variables that I have to take into consideration.  Making a universal template, or at least a template that can service 9/10 clients has proved to be a real chore.

Comment: I have no knowledge of arrays, but it seems like I should be able to store the raw data in an array and pull from it based on variable criteria (Adjuster Home Office, Line Type, Coverage Code, Claim Type, State of Jurisdiction, etc).  My main objective is to organize the raw data by Adjuster Home Office.  Then i'll need to be able to tell the macro what im looking for, and organize it by the criteria I provide.

Comment: If you want to pull data based on criteria, you want a collection, not an array. A collection is essentially a 2 element array of the type `Key`, `Value`. In my "answer", the key is the office and the value is an object that has all the properties of your data (eg, loosely an array of arrays). So, you can pull an individual office's data up with the code `set HO = col.Item("BOCA RATON, FL")` Then you can look at individual stats for that office like this: `HO.MedicalOnly` (assuming you create a MedicalOnly property in the Class Module.

Comment: Its not clear from the example data how the different states with different rates correlates to the example of what you're trying to get. If it's based on the State Of Jurisdiction, one of your HomeOffice properties could be `SoJ`. Then you could use a `Select Case` statement to determine the rate that should be applied to that state. EG, `Select Case HO.SoJ Case "MN", "TX", "CA" Rate = 1.5 End Select`

Comment: I added a picture of my objective.  If this is impossible, then so be it.  I will just have to move in a different direction

Comment: Hopefully those aren't real Account Numbers! :) But yes, the code I posted will do that. It's all a matter of structuring you loop to put the data where you want it. I'll edit the code in my answer to make it print out like your picture.

Comment: lol I just removed the account #'s.  they were mostly fictional but rather be safe than sorry.  Thanks!

Comment: this seems to static to me.  The "Line Items" are often different for each client.  The line items, states, rates, are all variables and I don't see how this gives me the flexibility I need.  I added another picture which shows where the list of line items is populated by a userform, and imported from.

Comment: Ahh... My apologies then for steering you down a wrong path. It appeared from the pictures that each office( Atlanta, Aurora, Boca, etc) each had exactly the same 10 categories. This may not be the best method for your needs. Sorry! :(

Comment: no worries, I appreciate the effort regardless.  I should have been more clear up front.